# Can I make C# Console applications on Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, console, c#, visual-studio-2012

As the question, can I make C# console applications on Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows 8?
I am aware that you can create Windows 8 apps but is there a template to create C# based console applications?

Comment: You'll need `Express for Windows Desktop` to create traditional `console` programs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Bob commented: you need desktop version:

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2012-express

Here are listed all versions. For some reason, Windows 8 means tiles for microsoft. You can create desktop applications, which work on the "metro" environment on a normal PC, with that "... for windows 8" version.

Comment: Too much costly to install another express instance of Visual Studio. Should the answer below get accepted http://superuser.com/a/620284/34893

Comment: Why not yes. I personally like several instances for different targets. Same with other ides

Comment: As I said. It's just too costly ^^

Answer (score 5):

Here is another solution in the link below: (Creating a Console App in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web)
http://possiblythemostboringblogever.blogspot.com.au/2012/08/creating-console-app-in-visual-studio.html

The main point is like: 
I've installed and am using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web as my primary IDE for C#. There isn't a template for a console application.

So if you want 1980s goodness, create a new `Class Library` project and on the `Project Properties` page, setting `Output Type` to `Console Application`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sure, You can create console application from visual studio 2012 Express.
Visual studio 2012 express has no separate template for Console application.But it has template for class library.
One solution you can find here .
http://w3techno.blogspot.in/2014/04/create-console-application-in-visual.html

Comment: Hi Chandrasen - when referencing an external link, please summarise the content of the link so that the answer still stands if the link breaks.  You can edit your answers with the edit link below your answer.

Comment: Yeah as Paul said, need a snapshot content for external link backing up for broken link(s)